# Image Segmentation: (Efficient Graph-Based)

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning

This question is two-fold; First, it is about how to get the speed efficiency this algorithm should provide in Mathematica. In addition, it has a small question about the algorithm ([Efficient Graph-Based Image Segmentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXN0g.jpg)) itself.

## Code

First we need an image. I am using my own (as seen in the included photos), so please replace `<your-image>` with your image.

```
img = <your-image>;
simg = ImageResize[img, 50] (* resize for debugging purposes *)
```

[image]

[image]

So as a pre-requisite, we need to make a k-Nearest Neighbors (KNN) graph, which means we need to be working on the pixel values themselves.

```
(* list of list of pixels {{pix11, pix21,...pixw1},...,{pix1h,...,pixwh}} *)
\[ScriptCapitalD] = ImageData[simg];
(* list of pixels {pix11, pix21,...pixw1,...,pix1h,...,pixwh} *)
ℱ = Partition[Flatten[\[ScriptCapitalD]], {3}];

k = 8
\[ScriptCapitalG] = NearestNeighborGraph[ℱ, k]
(* Short hand for the lazy *)
\[ScriptCapitalV] = 
  VertexList[\[ScriptCapitalG]];
ℰ = EdgeList[\[ScriptCapitalG]];
```

With our KNN graph in hand, we can work on the functions.

First, we need the weight function for our edges. The weight of an edge, $(v_i, v_j)$ is defined as the absolute difference of pixel intensity of each pixel (vertex):

$$
w((v_i, v_j)) = \lvert I(v_i) - I(v_j) \rvert
$$

This weight is meant to be a scalar, so what exactly the authors meant about pixel intensity (often derived from a histogram over many pixels), is lost on me.

For now, we will use the y channel of the rgb to luminance conversion:

```
Luminance[r_, g_, b_] := .299 r + .587 g + .114 b;
Luminance[pixel_List] := 
  Luminance[pixel[[1]], pixel[[2]], pixel[[3]]];
```

Which makes our weight function:

```
weight[edge_] := Abs@(Subtract @@ Luminance /@ edge)
```

Next, we will need the minimum internal difference, which requires the internal difference, a function called tau, and the maximum weight of an edge in the minimum spanning tree (MST) of the subgraph given the component.

```
τ[C_, k_] := Infinity /; Length@C == 0; (* error handling empty components *)
τ[C_, k_] := k/Length@C;


internalDifference[G_, C_] := -Infinity /; Length@C == 0; 
internalDifference[G_, C_] := 0 /; Length@C == 1;
internalDifference[G_, C_] := 
  Max[weight /@ EdgeList@FindSpanningTree@Subgraph[G, C]] /; 
   Length@C > 1; (* need at least 2 vertices to have edge wieghts *)


minimumInternalDifference[G_, k_, C1_, C2_] := Min[{
   internalDifference[G, C1] + τ[C1, k],
   internalDifference[G, C2] + τ[C2, k]
   }]
```

We also need to know what component the vertices of the edge are in:

```
findComponent[segmentation_, pixel_] := 
 First@First@Position[segmentation, pixel] (* note: this might be a bit buggy. Obviously if the pixel is not in the segmentation, this will throw an error. Also, I personally dislike using first, first to extract the value. Let me know of better alternatives. *)
```

With this information, there are only a few things left. 
We still need the function that makes the new segmentation from the old segmentation:

```
makeSn[G_, k_, segmentation_, edge_] := Module[
  {i, j, Ci, Cj, s, S},
  i = findComponent[segmentation, First@edge];
  j = findComponent[segmentation, Last@edge];
  Ci = segmentation[[i]];
  Cj = segmentation[[j]];
  If[
   (i != j) ∧ (weight[edge] <= 
      minimumInternalDifference[G, k, Ci, Cj]), (* condition from paper *)
   s = Union[Ci, Cj];
   (* we need to define S, as in modules, local vars can not be changed. *)
   S = Part[segmentation, 
     Table[If[MemberQ[{i, j}, z], Nothing, z], {z, 
       Length@segmentation}]];
   (* Since merging two components, we take all but those two components and append the merger *)
   S = Append[S, s];
   Return[S],
   S = segmentation;
   Return[S]
   ];
  ]
```

We need the order of the edges, and the initial segmentation:

```
p = SortBy[ℰ, weight]; (* should be non-decreasing order *)
S = Table[{}, {i, Length@p + 1}]; (* S[[1]] is initial segmentation, the rest are for each iteration over the ordered edges *)
S[[1]] = Table[{\[ScriptCapitalV][[i]]}, {i, Length@\[ScriptCapitalV]}]; (* starts with each vertex in its own component *)
```

and now we can do the iteration:

```
Table[S[[i + 1]] = makeSn[\[ScriptCapitalG], k, S[[i]], p[[i]]], {i, 
   Length@p}];
```

To see what we made, we need a color function:

```
c[i_, l_] := ColorData["BrightBands"][i/(l + 1)] (* might not be the best coloring option *)
```

and we need to map pixels to their new colors:

```
(* This could be a bit buggy if there are at least two pixels with identical values - although this is not an error with the above algorithm. We just need a way to show the pixels, colored by components, where they originally are in the image. *)
(* The outer table extracts the positions of the pixels for each segment and the inner table maps those positions to the components color *)
repl = Table[Table[
   f -> c[i, Length@chosenSegmentation], {f, 
    Flatten[Position[\[ScriptCapitalF], chosenSegmentation[[i]][[j]], 1]]}], {i, 
   Length@chosenSegmentation}, {j, Length@chosenSegmentation[[i]]}];
```

And then do the replacement

```
Image[Partition[
  ReplacePart[ℱ, 
   Flatten@repl], {Length@First@\[ScriptCapitalD]}]]
```

In the paper they state that for 320x240 images, they use $k=300$ and for smaller, $k=150$.

Besides the KNN taking a very long to generate at large K (even at modest image size of ~100x50 pixels), I have noticed that this (in my tests) always end up converging to 1 component. I can, of course, select a previous segmentation (say with 10 components), so I was curious as to why this might be the case. My assumptions are that it has to do with using a wrong pixel intensity value, or using a wrong error handling value (e.g. -Infinity).

If we pick a segmentation of 50:

[image]

Where we can see that some of the main things are separated (sea, sky, boat, frame).

I would appreciate any feedback.

To recap the two questions are:

1.) given above, how to more efficiently do the `makeSn` function (as well as KNN graph) to segment images more readily?
2.) what is single pixel value intensity?
3.) why does this always converge to a segmentation of 1 component?